# Using Bootstrap React Accordion

Tags: reactjs, accordion, react-bootstrap

I want to use Bootstrap's Accordion in my React project and I downloaded npm package for it.

So basically I want to use it like this:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

// reactstrap components
import {
  Card,
  CardBody,
  CardHeader,
  CardTitle,
  Row,
  Col,
} from "reactstrap";

import Accordion from 'react-bootstrap/Accordion';

// core components
import PanelHeader from "components/PanelHeader/PanelHeader.js";


export default function Orders() {

  return (
    <>
      <PanelHeader size="sm" />
      <div className="content">
        <Row>
          <Col xs={12}>
            <Card>
              <CardHeader>
                <CardTitle tag="h4">ORDERS</CardTitle>
              </CardHeader>
              <CardBody>
              <Accordion defaultActiveKey="0">
                <Card>
                  <Accordion.Toggle as={Card.Header} eventKey="0">
                    Click me!
                  </Accordion.Toggle>
                  <Accordion.Collapse eventKey="0">
                    <Card.Body>Hello! I'm the body</Card.Body>
                  </Accordion.Collapse>
                </Card>
                <Card>
                  <Accordion.Toggle as={Card.Header} eventKey="1">
                    Click me!
                  </Accordion.Toggle>
                  <Accordion.Collapse eventKey="1">
                    <Card.Body>Hello! I'm another body</Card.Body>
                  </Accordion.Collapse>
                </Card>
              </Accordion>
              </CardBody>
            </Card>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

But I am getting an error like this:
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

So do you have any idea why I am getting this error?

Thanks...

Comment: I'm looking through it now, on first glance I'll say you should really name your function component here. Its not great especially during development to have unnamed default exports. -- Does the error point to which component is causing the problem?

Comment: I think this one because whenever I delete it, it works fine import Accordion from 'react-bootstrap/Accordion';

Comment: what npm package did you install? 'react-bootstrap/Accordion' or 'react-bootstrap'

Comment: 'react-bootstrap'

Comment: but isnt Accordion inside of 'react-bootstrap'

Comment: yeah, I was double checking if the paths were the same. That part seems fine. How do you export PanelHeader?

Comment: I think when you have <CardHeader> and <CardBody> and <CardTitle> those should be <Card.Header> <Card.Body> and <Card.Title>. I'm not seeing CardHeader, CardBody, CardTitle in the module

Comment: OK! I think I see the problem. You're using Accordion.Toggle as={Card.Header} which Card.Header would be if you imported Card from react-bootstrap. You're using reactstrap, so that should be CardHeader. Try in the Accordion.Toggle as={} putting CardHeader instead of Card.Header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, as I was saying in the comments its an issue of the modules you're importing.

You're using

```
import {
  Card,
  CardBody,
  CardHeader,
  CardTitle,
  Row,
  Col,
} from "reactstrap";
```

for your Card components, but you're using the `Accordion.Toggle as={Card.Header}` from the API doc example. Here they are using the `<Card />` component within the package `'react-bootstrap'`. To get the header from *this* Card, you call it as a property of the Card object like this: `Card.Header`.

You are using `<CardHeader /> from 'reactstrap'` so you need to do this in your Accordion.Toggle components:

```
//this
Accordion.Toggle as={CardHeader}

//not this

Accordion.Toggle as={Card.Header}
```

Such a little thing, but be careful when using multiple styling packages because they often have very similar names!

**Additionally, and I would recommend this**

Use just one library for your style components. If `'reactstrap'` doesn't have that Accordion functionality you're looking for, consider using the style components from `'react-bootstrap'` instead.

This way you can be sure that you're always using the same component that you're important and one little period or dot doesn't crash your program.

I use Material UI : `'@material-ui/core'` so I'm a bit biased here, but I absolutely love it,